# Google fusiontables.query.sqlGet 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

Previously working API key and Queries, stopped working when an API key expired and was renewed for 24 hours. Enabling oAuth in Google console returns results just fine.
Can API key be restricted to just one or more functions?, or What is the difference between .query and .column from an API key authentication perspective?

Executing fusiontables.column.get from google console returns:
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/1v8JskMBigFi_dyKLi9DiWxrjYvxIZGUs3I83Apw/columns/HOOD_NAME?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

200 OK

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  public, max-age=60, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  94
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Wed, 19 Feb 2014 04:43:29 GMT
etag:  "HOxOdYkkMATeVH_EjDMiDjtXeAo/Pk-8EZToRXev4BMX2vNA0SodSMc"
expires:  Wed, 19 Feb 2014 04:44:29 GMT
server:  GSE

```
{

 "kind": "fusiontables#column",
 "columnId": 3,
 "name": "HOOD_NAME",
 "type": "STRING"
}
```

I have checked new key has been passed to API and FusionTable has correct permission on a table.
Have i missed anything?  Can i have multiple API keys? Is there a document that describes when and how often API keys expire?

https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT+HOOD_NAME+FROM+1v8JskMBigFi_dyKLi9DiWxrjYvxIZGUs3I83Apw+WHERE+HOOD_ID+%3D+250&key={key_removed}
403 Forbidden

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  118
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Wed, 19 Feb 2014 04:05:12 GMT
expires:  Wed, 19 Feb 2014 04:05:12 GMT
server:  GSE

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable the download-option(it's required for read-access)?

Comment: This may be a bug. I recently had the reverse issue, data was readable although download was not allowed. You may try to query the base-table instead(works for me) or to use a copy of the table.